# F# find largest element in list of structures

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and I want to find largest element form list of structures:

```
type Element = struct
   val X: int
   val Y: int
   val RES: int

   new (x, y, res) =
     {X = x; Y = y; RES = res;}

   override this.ToString() = sprintf "%i = %i * %i" this.RES this.X this.Y
end
```

X is larger than Y when X.RES > Y.RES. I wrote some code:

```
let max2 x y = if x.RES < y.RES then y else x //BAD LINE

let max_list list =
   let rec loop hi list = 
       match list with 
       | h::t -> loop (max2 h hi) t
       | []   -> hi
   match list with
   | h::t -> loop h t
   | []   -> invalidArg "list" "Empty list"
```

and call:

```
let list = findPalindromes 1 1 List.empty //this call populates the "list"
printfn "%A" (max_list list)
```

This call generates 2 errors (pointing **x.RES** and **y.RES**) in line //BAD LINE:

> error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

I know that I should cast x and y to Element, I've tried to do it but every time I failed.

How can I fix this code or implement this functionality other way?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# standard library has this built-in – [`List.maxBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.maxby%5B%27t,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
findPalindromes 1 1 List.empty
|> List.maxBy (fun e -> e.RES)
|> printfn "%A"
```

As to the error you're getting with `max2`, type annotations solve it:

```
let max2 (x:Element) (y:Element) = if x.RES < y.RES then y else x
```